# Powershell Get-ADuser and Import-CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

I am trying to Import a CSV file that has the following fields:

```
Ticket      User
1234657     ABC1234
2456875     ABC9876
```

Where User = SamAccountName

I have the following code:

```
 $File = Import-CSV C:\\file.csv
 $File | ForEach  { Get-ADUser -Identity ($_.User) -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, @{Name=’Ticket';Expression={$_.ticket}}}
```

The output looks like the following:

```
SamAccountName       DisplayName          Ticket
--------------       -----------          ------
ABC1234              John, Doe
ABC9876              Jane, Doe
```

So something is happening where the ticket isn't populating in the output table...
I want it to look like the following:

```
SamAccountName       DisplayName          Ticket
--------------       -----------          ------
ABC1234              John, Doe            1234657
ABC9876              Jane, Doe            2456875
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with my code?

Also if I do just $_.Ticket instead of the expression statement it makes the individual ticket numbers as my header... 
Example:

```
SamAccountName  : ABC1234
DisplayName     : John, Doe
Description     : New Account
enabled         : True
1234657         : {}

SamAccountName  : ABC9876
DisplayName     : Jane, Doe
Description     : New Account
enabled         : True
2456875         : {}
```

Comment: No the capitals don't do anything... I have tried all the ways with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_` is the output from `Get-ADUser` when you reach `Select-Object`. You need to save the ticket at the start of the foreach-loop. Try:

```
$File = Import-CSV C:\\file.csv
 $File | ForEach  {
    #Save ticket
    $ticket = $_.ticket

    Get-ADUser -Identity ($_.User) -Properties * |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, @{Name='Ticket';Expression={$ticket}}
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, pretty simple but not at all on my mind.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe the results of Get-ADUser to Select-Object, that is what is in $_. Not your original CSV. Here is one solution:

```
 $File | ForEach  {$t = $_.Ticket; Get-ADUser -Identity ($_.User) -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, @{Name=’Ticket';Expression={$t}}}
```